# PHP check inheritance in a static way

Tags: php, inheritance, static

I wonder if it is possible to check the inheritance of a class in a static way.

In cases I get just a class name with its namespace I can do:

```
    $oObject = new $sClassName();
    if(is_a($oObject, $sParentClassName)) { return true; }
```

But here it is mandatory to have an instance of that class.

The only static check I have found so far is the following:

```
    if(method_exists($sClassName, $sMethodNameFromParent)) { return true; }
```

But checking just for a method is no good, because I can't be sure whether the class in question inherited it from that specific parent, some other parent or implemented it all by itself.

Is there any way to check the inheritance in a static manner?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php ?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @xmike: so you suggest to use a while loop to iterate through all parents until I find the searched one or reach the root?

Comment: @axiac I've got a bunch of class names and have to pick those who inherit from a specific parent. I have no direct control of the number or types of class names.

Comment: Finding the parent class is not a goal *per se*. You are probably interested in the functionality provided by the parent class more than its name (that could change without affecting its functionality). You should check if the required feature is implemented by the class, not what classes it extends.

Comment: @axiac so I should look for a specific method? Any class could implement a method with that name...

Comment: I cannot imagine any good reason why you need to find the name of the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection::isSubclassOf](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.issubclassof.php) for this.

```
class A {}
class D {}
class B extends D {}
class C extends B {}

$reflected = new ReflectionClass('C');

echo $reflected->isSubclassOf('B'); // true
echo $reflected->isSubclassOf('D'); // true
echo $reflected->isSubclassOf('A'); // false
```

No instance of `C` will be created, and will work even if the class has `__construct` arguments

Comment: This works like a charm! While searching for `ReflectionClass->isSubclassOf()` I've stubled across `is_subclass_of($sClassName, $sParentName)` which works without instantiating a ReflectionClass. Does either of the two use the functionality of the other?

Answer (score 0):

```
$oObject = new $sClassName();
if( get_parent_class($oObject) == $sParentClassName ) { return true; }
```

[PHP function to get parent class name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php)

Comment: This will only work if checked against a direct parent, i.e., will return false when checking for parent of a parent.

Comment: This is not a static check. This instantiates an object, which I did not want.